# How to play video as a background on website without breaking?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to add video to my website as background video.

But it not loading smoothly.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

This is the code which i used.

```
<video id="bgVideo" preload="true" autoplay  loop muted poster="images/loading-landing.jpg" >
    <source src="videos/Main-Page.mp4" type="video/mp4" > 
</video>
```

Comment: a tip for showing videos on your website it creates a lot of traffic and will make rendering slow.. usually some people will use Iframe or like youtube gives you a feature for embedding a video from there website like the Iframe, it helps for rendering. you can check out the settings for your case to display it in the background to hide the pause/play etc.. features.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this also..

**HTML**

```
<div class="Video-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="video/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Video-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.Video-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```